# How can store only 10 rows in table

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have to fill database with maximum 10 rows, any ideas how to do that?

I only know how to limit queries, but in this case I have to save maximum 10 rows to database

Comment: That's a very strange requirement. Please tell us more what the purpose of this will be

Comment: I will write a documentation about task, so I have to write operation to fill the database up to maximum 10 beers, I have to consume https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers and if you open this link you'll see that there is 25 beers, so I have to limit my database to store only 10 beers (maximum). This is giving me a headache...

Comment: So why don't you check if there are already 10 beers before you insert a new beer?

Comment: Hmm I wasn't thinking about that, so to put if statement to check if there is already a 10 beers in a database?

Comment: Sure that's the way to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this is best solved by creating the elements beforehand and disallowing the direct creation. Instead, you assign the elements through some means either delete the rows or set some column i.e. "consumed".